# Issue when Selecting Data from PHP Select Statement, Getting Duplicate data

Tags: php, mysql

I'm having issue with getting duplicate data when trying to inner join or just plain out select data from a table in MYSQL, I have checked to make sure there is no duplicate data and there is none in between it. What I'm trying to do is make it where it will SELECT * FROM friends INNER JOIN users ON friends.friendsid = users.id And then Inner join Newsfeed and Comments But when I'm doing that it's giving me duplicate posts.

Any Ideas on Whats causing this or How I'm able to fix this? Thanks In Advance!

Here is my PHP For That Select Statement:

```
  $stmt = $DB_con->prepare("SELECT * FROM friends INNER JOIN users ON friends.friendsid = users.id
INNER JOIN newsfeed on newsfeed.userid = friends.friendsid
INNER JOIN comments on comments.post_id = newsfeed.statusid
WHERE friends.userid = :user_id");
$stmt->bindParam(':user_id', $_SESSION['user']['id']);
$stmt->execute();
while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
{
```

This is what it does when I run that Command in PHPMYADMIN: 
[What it looks like after running the Select statement](https://i.stack.imgur.com/86L4Y.png)

Here is what my Newsfeed Table looks like:

[Newsfeed Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JRvhR.png)

Here is my Comments Table: 
[Comments Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jGgbJ.png)

Newsfeed Table Dump: 
    --
    -- Table structure for table `newsfeed`
    --

```
CREATE TABLE `newsfeed` (
  `statusid` int(255) NOT NULL,
  `post_id` int(128) NOT NULL,
  `userid` int(255) NOT NULL,
  `status` varchar(1000) NOT NULL,
  `image` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `uploaddate` datetime NOT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

--
-- Dumping data for table `newsfeed`
--

INSERT INTO `newsfeed` (`statusid`, `post_id`, `userid`, `status`, `image`, `uploaddate`) VALUES
(51, 0, 0, 'KABOOM!!! :) ', '', '2018-10-10 07:13:38'),
(52, 52, 2, 'How about the refresh?!? ', '5bbe4ff2cc509.jpg', '2018-10-10 07:16:02'),
(53, 0, 3, 'Here is a new post from trail how does this look? ', '', '2018-10-16 09:31:24'),
(54, 0, 3, 'Background v3 :) ', '5bc658ba57573.jpg', '2018-10-16 09:31:38');

--
-- Indexes for dumped tables
--
```

Comments Table Dump:

```
--
-- Table structure for table `comments`
--

CREATE TABLE `comments` (
  `comment_id` int(128) NOT NULL,
  `post_id` int(128) NOT NULL,
  `comment_from` int(128) NOT NULL,
  `comment` varchar(500) NOT NULL,
  `comment_date` datetime NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

--
-- Dumping data for table `comments`
--

INSERT INTO `comments` (`comment_id`, `post_id`, `comment_from`, `comment`, `comment_date`) VALUES
(1, 52, 2, 'This is a Comment from user 2', '0000-00-00 00:00:00'),
(2, 51, 1, 'This is a comment for post id 51 from user id 1 ', '0000-00-00 00:00:00'),
(5, 52, 1, 'Post comment 3', '2018-10-16 09:18:14');

--
-- Indexes for dumped tables
--
```

And then I ended up making a Middle Table But am Still getting duplicate data:
Here is the middle table called newsfeed_comment

```
--
-- Table structure for table `newsfeed_comment`
--

CREATE TABLE `newsfeed_comment` (
  `id` int(128) NOT NULL,
  `post_id` int(128) NOT NULL,
  `comment_id` int(128) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

--
-- Dumping data for table `newsfeed_comment`
--

INSERT INTO `newsfeed_comment` (`id`, `post_id`, `comment_id`) VALUES
(1, 52, 1),
(2, 52, 2);

--
-- Indexes for dumped tables
--
```

Answer (score 0):

What you see in your image is just the product of the multiple tables.

In this example the post data is all the same but the comment data is different. You see the same post data because each comment is linked to that same post and your pulling out both the post data and the comment data.

For example

```
post
1

comment  post_id
1         1
2         1
```

You wind up with this

```
post comment
1    1
1    2
```

Because each post (each row) can have many comments.  So the same post gets represented in each row.  It's the only way the DB can display the data as a flat structure.

Comment: Is there a way to fix this? Or should I figure out a redesign to of the tables to try and fix this?

Comment: No, it's the expected results.  The only thing I would say that needs fixing is some of the naming conventions, for example `comments.post_id = newsfeed.statusid`  this is a bit confusing, joining post id to a status id?  Maybe your relationships are wrong, there is no way to know that without the schema for these tables and more information about what is in them.

Comment: I added the table dumps, I ended up making a joining table called newsfeed_comment which holds the post_id, and the comment_id and then I tried to inner join the `newsfeed_comment.comment_id on comments.comment_id` and also tried inner joining `newsfeed_comment.post_id on newsfeed.statusid` But its still giving duplicate data.

Comment: You mean a `junction table` (sometimes called a bridge table, too).  In any case, it's not duplicate data.  I don't know how else to explain it, it's the consequence of having a Many to One relationships, the side with the One, has to be repeated on the side with the Many.  There is no other way to show the data in a Flat structure.